# OpenCV Unspecified error when calling Hough transform in c++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, hough-transform, unspecified

I'm working on a music recognition Android app, which should recognize music annotations in sheet in real time using camera.

When I try to recognize lines or circles using Hough transform (either HoughCircles or HoughLinesP), I get the Unspecified error:

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvWaitKey, file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 567
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 7772 (Thread-411)
```

I could try another version of OpenCV, but I don't have enough time to change everything. I'm also not skilled with OpenCV, this is the first time I'm using it. Maybe the problem is in c++ file or header.

C++ file:

```
#include "com_ryu_musicreader_OpencvClass.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ryu_musicreader_OpencvClass_musicDetection
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba){
Mat& frame = *(Mat*)addrRgba;

find_lines(frame);
find_circles(frame);
}

void find_lines(Mat& src){

Mat dst, cdst;
Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);

cvtColor(dst, cdst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );

for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 0);
}

imshow("detected lines", cdst);

}

int find_circles(Mat& src){

Mat src_gray;

cvtColor(src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

vector<Vec3f> circles;

HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );

for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
    circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
}

namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );    
imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );

waitKey(0);
return 0;

}
```

Header file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
#ifndef _Included_com_ryu_musicreader_OpencvClass
#define _Included_com_ryu_musicreader_OpencvClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void detect(Mat& frame);

void find_lines(Mat& frame);

int find_circles(Mat& frame);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ryu_musicreader_OpencvClass_musicDetection
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

It's highly possible that there's something wrong with the code, since I'm not entirely sure how the Hough transform works, so I tried to use some implementations that I found online.

I'd really appreciated any help.

Comment: The error is with `imshow`, not the hough transform. _Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script)_

Comment: I tried to comment everything except Hough transform function, and it still crashes on that function. And that rebuilding, I'm not very confident with Android (besides coding) and I don't know how to rebuild it with those parameters, and I'm kind of afraid to do that. Any simple tutorial or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I'm stupid. I didn't know that this implementation is for Desktop purposes, and I was trying to use it on Android. I should really read all the docs in the library I'm using.